# convert dates using moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am having a date object

```
const resDate={startDate: "Fri Apr 21 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", endDate: "Tue Apr 25 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"}
```

my aim is to get startDate and endDate in a format like  const

```
const resDate={startDate:2022-09-01T00:00:00+05:30,endDate: 2022-09-01T00:00:00+05:30}
```

and so on values doesn't make sense in this example the format of conversion matters .I used moment js to carry out this task and created a function for this

```
const getDate=()=>{
let effTime = moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      let istTime= effTime + "T00:00:00+05:30";
return isTime;
}
```

but this doesn't seems to be the right approach as i am hardcoding something in the function .is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: That "date object" is invalid JavaScript. Did you forget quotes?

Comment: never saw that error thanks

Comment: Same problem with the desired output: it is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, new developments with momentjs are [discouraged](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/). You could do this without momentjs though:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    const [, mmm, d, y, h, m, s, _, zh, zm] = date.match(/[+-]\d\d|\w+/g);
    const M = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec".indexOf(mmm) / 3;
    return new Date(Date.UTC(y, M, d, h, m, s)).toJSON().slice(0, 19) + zh+":"+zm;
}

// Example
const startDate = "Fri Apr 21 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
const result = formatDate(startDate);
console.log(result);
```